# What is the command for placing red wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to put red wool down with a command, and I've tried everything. `minecraft:red_wool`, `minecraft:redwool`, `minecraft:37:14`, but none of them work. I looked it up and it just tells me to put `minecraft:wool`, but that just places regular wool.

How can I put down red wool with a command?

Comment: Wow this question was on the hot network questions list!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351075-color-screens-with-the-new-setblock-command, https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool

Simple command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ wool <1-15>
```

Breakdown:

`/setblock` is the command. `~ ~ ~` is the 3 coordinates (X Y Z respectively). `wool` is the item that you place. `<1-15>` is the number that corresponds to the colour of the wool in Dec.

Here is the list:

```
 0 - white
 1 - orange
 2 - magenta
 3 - light blue
 4 - yellow
 5 - lime
 6 - pink
 7 - grey
 8 - light grey
 9 - cyan
10 - purple
11 - blue
12 - brown
13 - green
14 - red
15 - black
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.10 this no longer works!

In 1.10 you do /setblock X Y Z minecraft:wool 0

Comment: Also in 1.9 the <> don't work either

Comment: I did not know that! :P

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft 1.13 and later versions split red wool into it's own item, meaning the correct command is now `/setblock x y z red_wool`